# In my profile, how can I see all Tags for which I have earned Gold Badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, profile-page, tag-badges

I'm trying to find out for which tags I have earned Gold Badges. In my profile I found this section:

[image]

But this shows a looooong list of tags indicating how many gold badges have been awarded for it in total.

[image]

I see a green checkbox next to two tags. Does that mean I have earned two gold badges?

Is there any way I can see the gold tag badges just for my profile rather than having to scroll through the entire list (I may have missed one)?

Is there any way I can see my progress towards achieving a gold badge for a given tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean I have earned two gold badges?

Yes, you have earned two gold tag badges.

> Is there any way I can see the gold tag badges just for my profile rather than having to scroll through the entire list (I may have missed one)?

There are two ways:

1. As tag badges are also badges, you can get a list of all badges you got by clicking on the "*N* Badges" link in your profile. You can sort by "class" to get the gold tag badges at the top.
   [image: Badges]
2. In your list of tags, look at your tags for which you have 1k or more. Hover with your mouse of the score and you will see how many questions and answers you have in that tag. If your tag score is 1k or greater and you have 200 non-wiki answers in that tag, you have a gold tag badge for it. Note that a tag has to appear on 100 questions to get a tag badge for that tag. You'll have to go to the question list of that tag to see how many questions it has.
   [image: Tags]

> Is there any way I can see my progress towards achieving a gold badge for a given tag?

You can use the same way as the second list item I provided above.

Comment: Note that the tag display doesn't show you what tags have the minimum 100 questions listed. When you have 200 answers, it is *extremely likely* there are that many questions, of course.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, I forgot about that requirement. I edited my answer - thanks!

Comment: I have one tag at score 624, with 39 answers and 0 badges; we haven't quite reached 100 questions yet for the tag. Even if we do reach 100 questions, at my current rate I'll reach 3k upvotes before I have enough answers accumulated for a gold badge.

Answer (score 1):

(Possible since the new profile page)

Go to [your profile](/users/current) and perform the following steps:

> [image]

If you are 25k+ user (5k+ on beta), skip the first step.

You'll see the popup allowing to select the next badge, and also to view the ones you've earned already. To see them, click the badge type you want, or click *all* to see all the tag badges you've earned. The earned badges go first, slightly greyed out and ticked.

E.g. this is what I see with the *Silver* tab selected:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

In your profile click on the **Tags** link.  You should have a gold badge for all the tags that are marked **1k** or greater.  Note that you also need to know if you have 200 non-CW answers which you can find by hovering over the score.

[image: Gold Tags]

[image: Gold Tag Score Hover]

So, yes, the green checkmark indicates you have the gold badge for that tag.

Comment: There's a minimum post requirement as well - just looking for 1k tags isn't enough

Comment: I suppose there may be an edge case somewhere where someone didn't meet the post requirements, but still have a 1k score in that tag, but not a high probability.

Comment: This isn't reliable. You need a) 200 *non-CW answers* (not obvious until you look at the tooltip), b) 1k upvotes and c) a tag with a at least 100 questions. The latter is *sort of* implied when you have 200 answers, but as you can add multiple answers per question, not a given.

Comment: I'm sure you could find a number of examples on Stack Overflow where a user has provided an extremely popular answer but hasn't done much else

Comment: If you are looking at the profile already *anyway*, look at the *badges* instead; sorted by class.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Jon Skeet has *at least* 34 tags over 1K but fewer than 200 answers. It happens far more than you think.

Comment: I agree @MartijnPieters, but those aren't sorted as well.  You'll have to look through the list, and maybe go to additional pages.